# Activity still staying over previous activity in Android Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, back-stack

The situation is I call an activity from my RouteActivity by:

```
arrived.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if(aBoolean==true){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(), RouteCompleteActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.do_nothing);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

That is fine then when I close the activity by calling:

```
Intent navIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(), NavigationStartActivity.class);
                navIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(navIntent);
                finish();
```

This takes me back to my main NavigationStartActivity, then when I again choose to go back to my RouteActivity the original, the RouteCompleteActivity is still over the top of it? so instead of RouteActivity I get RouteCompleteActivity then if I press back it goes to the RouteActivity?? as if it has remembered some backstack? can anyone explain this?

Comment: @PamIx So when I next call an intent to get my RouteActivity i actualy get the RouteCompleteActivity, is that normal behaviour? If so that is fine how do i ensure that when i call RouteActivity i get just that?

Comment: I am initially calling RouteCompleteActivity from RouteActivity, so the Observer code is in RouteActivity, this calls RouteCompleteActivity then, i go to my NavigationStartActivity via the next intent. Now the next time i call an intent to get RouteActivity i actually get in the UI RouteCompleteActivity, but, if i then press back it goes to RouteActivity? It's complicated to describe but i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using a LiveData from a viewModel or repository which keeps its value. The case is like this: `arrived` has a `true` value and `onChanged` will be called. The next time RouteActivity observes arrived, onChanged will be called again because it already has a value and another `startAcrivity` will be called. A simple solution would be using `SingleLiveEvent` instead which was created by google long time ago [link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

```
public class SingleLiveEvent<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {

private static final String TAG = "SingleLiveEvent";

private final AtomicBoolean mPending = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@MainThread
public void observe(LifecycleOwner owner, final Observer<T> observer) {

    if (hasActiveObservers()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.");
    }

    // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
    super.observe(owner, new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t);
            }
        }
    });
}

@MainThread
public void setValue(@Nullable T t) {
    mPending.set(true);
    super.setValue(t);
}

/**
 * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
 */
@MainThread
public void call() {
    setValue(null);
}
}
```

It simply calls `onChange` when a new value is set. I also recommend to take a look at [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) article which describes it deeper